# Properties preserved by fppf morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> Which properties P do fppf morphisms preserve? In other words if $f: X \to Y$ is fppf and $Y$ has P, for which P does $X$ also have P?

I'm particularly interested in the cases when P=smooth or P=proper.

Comment: Did you look at the [descent chapter](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/chapter/34) in the Stacks project? You are basically asking about whether something or other is a property that is fppf-local on the source.

Comment: @ZhenLin I'll have a look at it. By the way, do you know if the answer is positive for the properties smooth or proper? If not, do you know any counterexamples to keep in mind? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question with smooth and proper. These are properties of a morphism not of a scheme. Do you mean, if $Y$ is smooth or proper over some base $S$ (a field ?) does $X$ has this property ? In that case it is obviously false : if $Y$ is a field, any morphism of finite presentation $X\rightarrow Y$ is fppf, but $X$ may be not proper, singular...

Comment: @user113969 Yes that's what I meant (X smooth = $X \to S$ smooth for some base $S$). Also thanks for the counterexamples, I should have thought of that.